# Cannot access property of Ember.js model

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I have a problem accessing model properties in Ember.js

**Model:**

```
App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

**Controller:**

```
App.BlocksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  pages: function() {
    return App.Page.find();
  }.property(),

  pageTree: function() {
    var pages = this.get('pages.content'),
        pageTree = new Tree();
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        console.log( pages[i], pages[i].id, pages[i].parent );
    }
    pageTree.insertList(pages);
    return pageTree;
  }.property('pages.@each'),

});
```

I use the `pageTree` property in a template/view. The `console.log` does print me objects that have been retrieved from the API (incl. `id`), however, I cannot access its properties (`parent` giving me `undefined`, but it's in the API response).

One `console.log` lines looks like this:

```
Object {id: "5", clientId: 19, type: function, data: Object, prematerialized: Object…}
"5"
undefined
```

I assume that using `pages.@each` as a property, the `pageTree` property should be bound to the (loaded) pages array.

Yes, `pages` is not the model that is controlled by the ArrayController, but a secondary set of models.

**When I use `{{#each pages}}{{parent}}{{/each}}` in the template, it works!** So I guess, the problem has to do with the data bindings?

For reference, I'm on Ember 1.0.0-rc.6.1, ember-data 0.13, ember-data-django-rest-adapter 0.13

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks to the IRC:

```
pageTree: function() {
  var pages = this.get('pages'),
    pageTree = new Tree();
  pages.forEach(function(page) {
    //console.log(page, page.get('parent'));
    pageTree.insertAt(page.get('parent'), page );
  });
  return pageTree;
}.property('pages.@each'),
```

So, no `.content`, but `forEach` and `.get()`.

Comment: so this is how you do it just even if the accounts array length is 1?

Comment: ie this.get("accounts.length") === 1
in a controller
this.get("accounts[0].id") is undefined